# how to "batch replace" for a lot of files in emeditor

Tags: emeditor

yes,I know "Batch Replace All"，but

my replace list is so big,has 200+ items, i will use it in a big folder which has a lot of files.

now,emediter's behave is that use item1 in all files,then use item2 in all files.....

expected: use item1....item200 in file1,and use item1...item200 in file2

how to do it ?

I attempt use the macros(openfile,replace,closefile),but it is very slowly because open a file need 50ms

emeditor 19.9.1

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var files = [];
var filesHasModified = [];
function showFolderFileList(folderspec) {    
    var f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec);
    if(/\\(doc|lib|\.git|\.idea|\.vs|dll)$/gi.test(folderspec)){
        return;
    }

    // recurse subfolders
    var subfolders = new Enumerator(f.SubFolders);
    for(; !subfolders.atEnd(); subfolders.moveNext()) {
        showFolderFileList((subfolders.item()).path);
    }  

    // display all file path names.
    var fc = new Enumerator(f.files);
    for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext()) {
         var file = fc.item();
         if(/\.(jmx|config|cs|Config|tt|ttinclude|txt|yml|java|bak|xml|cshtml|sh|yaml|js|json|md|properties)$/gi.test(file)){
            files.push(file);
            }

    }

}

showFolderFileList('D:\\Sources.git2');




for( i in files)
{

    var file = files[i];





    editor.OpenFile(file);
    document.selection.Replace("http://172xx","http://offline.esb.xx",eeReplaceAll,0);
    document.selection.Replace("http://172xx1","http://offline.esb.xx",eeReplaceAll,0);
    document.selection.Replace("http://172xx2","http://offline.esb.xx",eeReplaceAll,0);
    //....200 more

    if(document.Saved)
    {
        document.close();
    }
    else
    {
        filesHasModified.push(file);
        document.Save(file);
        document.close();
    }


}

editor.NewFile();
document.selection.Text = filesHasModified.join("\r\n");
```

[image: emeditor batch replace]

Comment: How many files exist in the folder that you need to search, and what is the average size of a file?

Comment: @Yutaka 35000 files,20KB per file. I know you are the owner, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will optimize **Batch Replace in Files** in a future version. Meanwhile, please try (normal) **Batch Replace** with the **Search All Documents in the Group** option. This is how you can do:

1. Update EmEditor to v19.2.2 (or later).
2. Open EmEditor, select **Tools** menu - **Customize** - **Tab** page, and select **None** from the **When Not Fit** drop-down list, and select **Fix to specified with** from the **Width** drop-down list.
3. Open all (or some) files with EmEditor. An easy way is to drag and drop multiple files from Windows Explorer into EmEditor.
4. In EmEditor, press `Ctrl + H` to show **Replace** dialog box, click **Batch >>**, set the **Search All Open Documents in the Group**, make sure the batch list is updated, and click the **Batch Replace All** button.

The (normal) Batch Replace will work as you expect (use item1....item200 in file1, and use item1...item200 in file2, etc.).

Comment: according to your instruction。and 
1.disable "Windows Defender Antivirus Service"
2.close windows audio
3.close explorer.exe

then 
use everything filter,get the files,drop to emeditor
1.open files:10m
2.replace :2m
3.then hang:5m
4.save all:5m。

great satisfaction，Looking forward to the new version

Comment: I am glad it works. In the Tab page of the Customize dialog, also select "Fix to specified with" from the "Width" drop-down list, and 5-minute hang after replace will become less. I've updated the answer.